# What do Docker layers reduce?

Tags: docker

Docker images are created from base image via layers and during export each layer is dumped into final archive.

Theoretically (and for local dev environment that is true) it can save drive space.

Does layering improve container spin time? I can imagine that you may not unpack 1-2 GB of modern "mikro-service" images if they share base image and one already is running.

Does layering save RAM anyhow?

I think that Docker layering is marketing bullshit. I can't imagine that container manager in a real Big Cloud provider would care about spinning container on physical host with the same base image as already working container has.

Only recently Google came with 96 vCPU offer. I don't know usual vCPU configs, but can imagine that big players ask for 4-8-16 vCPU and it is half/quarter of all available CPU resources per host. Do container managers (like Kubernates/Mesos) really take in account not only available resources but also base images already in use?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused with docker image layers.

First of all, they are not archived or packaged (only when you export it in a tarball). Saving space is not the main purpose of docker layers.

But still, it will. Like if you want to run 4 MySQL container, docker will not create a copy of files to run MySQL 4 times. Another benefit can be reusability.

For example, if you have two images and both of them uses `ubuntu:latest` image, even though you will see that your image size, let's say 500 and 600mb. As ubuntu's image size is approximately 250mb, your actual image size is around 250mb and 450mb respectively.

This helps when you update your image and try to deploy it in the cloud. Docker will not push the whole image if the layers are already in the remote. It will only push the modified layers it finds in your latest image.

Second thing, Layering doesn't save RAM. It totally depends on the application. Layers are just filesystem. That provides necessary files to run your application.

Comment: When you talk about *docker push* do you mean to Docker registry? In case of bare  WEB server you won't have smartness of registry and need to upload entire image (all layers) to file storage, right?

Comment: I make conclusion that Docker layering is only for local development. It isn't used in a real Cloud environment and doesn't provide any benefits for production use of containers.

Comment: @gavenkoa think about the susequent push of image to the web server, if you change something in the code. Docker will track changes in these layers. Most of the cases will just upload less than 5mb instead of the whole image(Depends on how you write your Dockerfile).