# What benefits does having a separate "builder" Docker layer have?

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

Consider this Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache maven && \
    mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/target/dynamic-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "dynamic-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Why do I need these two separate layers? Why can't it be just

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache maven && \
    mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

CMD ["java", "-jar", "dynamic-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I read some Docker posts on SO (namely, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222377/what-are-docker-image-layers), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079114/should-i-minimize-the-number-of-docker-layers), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870377/what-do-docker-layers-reduce)), but I still don't understand. Will the first version's "builder" half be reused for later builds? If so, what and when exactly will be reused? Every time a Dockerfile needs a JDK 17 with Maven? Does the first image even make sense 'cause, I'll admit, generative AI gave me a hand with that (it works, though)?

Comment: Try both approaches and compare their sizes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) is to reduce the size of the final image produced by `docker build`.

Images that come equipped with build tools are usually larger than the ones required to run your code. In your case it's the same image. You could search the web to try and find a Java JRE image that's smaller than 140MB and use that one instead of [`amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/amazoncorretto/17-alpine-jdk/images/sha256-180e9c91bdbaad3599fedd2f492bf0d0335a9382835aa64669b2c2a8de7c9a22).

In addition, you don't want all your code and intermediary files generated by the build in your final image. You typically only need the executable JAR file. So what do you do? You only copy that file from the previous stage (in your case, the stage that's using the "builder" image), thus further reducing the final image size.

Comment: Thank you! Can you elaborate on your final sentence? Do you mean everything that's generated in the "builder" stage, except for the JAR, doesn't contribute to the size of the final image? What about "chain RUNs to keep temporary files from bloating your image"? I don't chain anything

Comment: *"Do you mean everything that's generated in the "builder" stage, except for the JAR, doesn't contribute to the size of the final image?"* - **Yes!**

Comment: But you do chain! Your `RUN` command combines two bash commands in a single `RUN` directive. This is considered good practice since. If you added one `RUN` command for each bash command, you'd add two layers to the image instead of a single one. I think this is out for scope for this question but it is well explained in the second question that you've linked in your OP.

Comment: Is the size of the image is the size of the final layer then?

Comment: It's the size of the last *stage*. So, all layers after and including the last `FROM` directive. And please ask separate questions for separate issues. The comments section is not meant for this. :)